# Checking a complete linear system on a curve is base point free

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a vague idea that I can check if a complete linear system |D| on a curve is base point free by comparing $h^0(D)$ and $h^0(D-P)$ for all points P on the curve.

Intuitively, I guess the idea is this: if all the sections of |D| already vanish at P, you don't lose any sections when you consider |D-P|.  Alternatively, if you gain a new section when you go from |D-P| to |D|, that section doesn't vanish at P.

However, these ideas seem to be bizarrely resistant to formalization.  Everything goes through fine if D is supported away from P, but if not I don't see how to do it, and since we're concerned about base points it's not as though we can move the support away from P in general.

Can someone show me a formal proof here?

Comment: I think this is spelled out in Ch 19 (the one about curves) in Vakil's notes. I could swear it's in the embedding section of Hartshorne's Ch IV but I'm too sleepy to look right now. Anyway, the vague idea is correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, consider the short exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathcal{O}_C(D-P) \to \mathcal{O}_C(D) \to \displaystyle \mathcal{O}_C(D)\big|_{P} \to 0$$ where the first map is multiplication by the section corresponding to the divisor $P$ and the second is restriction to $P$. Taking global sections, you get 
$$0 \to H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D-P)) \to H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D)) \to \displaystyle H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D)\big|_{P}) \to \ldots$$ Now observe that $H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D)\big|_{P}) \cong k$ since we're on a curve. We need to check that there's an element of $H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D))$ that doesn't vanish at $P$ which translates to the map $$H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D)) \to \displaystyle H^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D)\big|_{P}) \cong k$$ being surjective. Now this can happen only when $h^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D-P)) + 1 = h^0(\mathcal{O}_C(D))$ which is the criterion that you want.